# download image make and update table view after downloading

Tags: ios, asynchronous

I am working on an app which is image downloading. Images are of different sizes. I want to download image async and update table view when image downloading. Also need to clear cache on a time interval.

Please suggest me how to implement. I have seen SDwebimagecache but it is crashing on image downloading.

Comment: http://ezekiel.vancouver.wsu.edu/~wayne/yellowjacket/YellowJacket.zip try thi

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's can help you. I use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) with my all (ARC)projects.

using :

add your viewcontroller : `#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"`

```
   [yourImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ImageUrl"]];
```

you need to add **MapKit** and **ImageIO** to the project. if you didn't add

To do that:

Click on the project at the top of the project navigator in Xcode

Select the '**Build Phases**' tab.

Open up the '**Link Binary with Libraries**' box.

Click the '**+**'.

Add **MapKit and ImageIO** frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the core data and AFNetworking to achieve the same thing, find below my code

```
UserBasicInfo* userBasicInfo =  [[UserBasicInfo findByAttribute:@"userId" withValue:@(chatUser)] objectAtIndex:0];;

    if (userBasicInfo.userImage == nil) {
        __weak LGMessageBoxCell *weakCell = cell;
        [cell.userImage setImageWithURLRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:userBasicInfo.imageUrl]]
                              placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook-no-user.png"]
                                       success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
                                           weakCell.userImage.image = image;
                                           [weakCell setNeedsLayout];

                                           [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
                                               UserBasicInfo* userBasicInfo = [[UserBasicInfo findByAttribute:@"userId" withValue:@(chatUser) inContext:localContext] objectAtIndex:0];
                                               userBasicInfo.userImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
                                           } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                                               NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
                                           }];

                                       }
                                       failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                                       }];
    } else {
        cell.userImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:userBasicInfo.userImage];
    }
```